# How to count a column total with relationship in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I need to count the total amount of a column relationship.
I have two tables

```
people(id(int), infected(boolean)) and inventory(id(int) people_id(int Fk) water(float))
```

So I need to know how many waters I have per person whose "infected = true" and how many per person whose infected = false

in rails controller.

thanks for listening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the two tables and find per person water by aggregating based on infected.

Try this:

```
SELECT p.infected,
  SUM(i.water) / COUNT(p.people_id) water_per_person
FROM people p
INNER JOIN inventory i
ON p.id = i.people_id
GROUP BY p.infected;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to do this in rails